# Substracting Business Hours not working properly

Tags: apex

Hi I tried subtracting Business hours. But somehow it is not working properly. Below is the code snippet that I used.

```
date mydate = date.parse('11/13/2012');
Datetime dt =datetime.newInstanceGMT(mydate.year(), mydate.month(), mydate.day());
List <BusinessHours> bhList =  [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true] ;
Datetime newDt = BusinessHours.addGMT(bhList[0].id, dt, -(1*24* 60 * 60 * 1000));
System.debug('====='+dt+'====='+dt.format('EEEE')+'=>>>=='+newDt+'===='+newDt.format('EEEE'));
System.debug('====='+dt+'===='+(double)BusinessHours.diff(bhList[0].id, newDt,dt)/(1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L));
System.debug('========='+(double)BusinessHours.diff(bhList[0].id, datetime.newInstanceGMT(2012,11,13),datetime.newInstanceGMT(2012,11,12))/(1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L));`enter preformatted text here`
```

**Few assumptions in Business Hours:** All days other than sunday and saturday, working hours is 24 hours and for sunday and saturday No hours.

Problem : The above code is returning 2012-11-11 00:00:00(Sunday) for 2012-11-13 00:00:00(Tuesday) and business hours difference for this two date is showing .796

**Debug log of the above code :**

```
12:08:51.033 (33130000)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|=====2012-11-13 00:00:00=====Tuesday=>>>==2012-11-11 00:00:00====Sunday
12:08:51.033 (33443000)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|DEBUG|=====2012-11-13 00:00:00====0.7916666666666666
12:08:51.033 (33753000)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|=========-0.7916666666666666
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is coming up as expected, if you add the following two lines of debugging:

```
System.debug(1*24* 60 * 60 * 1000);
System.debug(BusinessHours.diff(bhList[0].id, newDt,dt));
```

You will see that the diff is equal to the amount of time you're adding.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the [BusinessHours Examples](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_businesshours.htm) have the input `startDate` in the local timezone rather than GMT.

It might be that the addGMT method is adjusting the `dt` input as though it was local time.

Comment: Well just wondering how to take everything in gmt